python sqlite - update cmd
I'm trying to update one of the db (sqlite3) fields using python and it doesn't work.
def update(self, old_name, new_name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(self._path, "files.db"))
    cursor = conn.cursor()  # Create a cursor

    try:
        query = f"UPDATE files SET filename ={new_name} WHERE filename = {old_name};"
        cursor.execute(query)

    except Exception as e:
        return e

    else:
        return True

    conn.close()

The code is supposed to change the file name.

We can't really help you without knowing any of the following:

The structure of the table
The error that is being returned (if an error is returned)
What does happen if not what you expect to happen?


Call conn.commit() after executing the query.
def update(self, old_name, new_name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(self._path, "files.db"))
    cursor = conn.cursor()  # Create a cursor


    try:
        query = f"UPDATE files SET filename ={new_name} WHERE filename = {old_name};"
        cursor.execute(query)
        conn.commit()


    except Exception as e:
        return e

    else:
        return True

    conn.close()

